# android download multiple images (using URL connection)

Tags: android, url

I am trying to download multiple image given a url. I have the following code which am stuck on. Could someone help me convert the depreciated http to URL?

```
            for (int i = 0; i < URLS.length; i++) {
                try {
                    File firstFile = new  File(directory + "/" + i + ".png");
                    if (firstFile.exists()==false)
                    {
                        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(URLS[i]);
                        HttpResponse resp = httpClient.execute(httpGet);

                        if(resp.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()==200){
                            HttpEntity entity = resp.getEntity();
 InputStream is = entity.getContent();

                            Boolean status = firstFile.createNewFile();

                            FileOutputStream fouts = new FileOutputStream(firstFile);
                            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                            long total = 0 ;
                            int count;

                            while ((count = is.read(buffer))!=-1){
                                total+=count;
                                fouts.write(buffer,0,count);
                            }
                            fouts.close();
                            is.close();
                            publishProgress(i);
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch(MalformedURLException e){e.printStackTrace();}

                catch(IOException e){e.printStackTrace();}
            }
            return null;
        }
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Object... values){
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: explain your problem.. what is not working exactly..

Comment: So, what is your problem? What do you want to achieve and what does not work? It would also be much better if you edited the code: leave only the parts relevant to the problem and fix formatting.

Comment: Sorry bout the vague problem description. I need help with the follow its getting errors every time wen i run.                                                    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                     HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(URLS[i]);
                      HttpResponse resp = httpClient.execute(httpGet);

                        if(resp.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()==200){
                            HttpEntity entity = resp.getEntity();
 InputStream is = entity.getContent();

Answer (score 0):

Use image loader

for reference

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-loading-image-from-url-http/

Answer (score 0):

Downloading images can be done simpler using Glide or picasso library, these are faster libraries to download images.
[Check this tutorial](https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/get-to-know-glide-recommended-by-google/en)